# Loop over $ rostopic pub ..... on NAO

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I would  like to have loop over the following command

rostopic pub /joint_angles nao_msgs/JointAnglesWithSpeed -- '[ 1, now, Head]' '[HeadYaw,HeadPitch]' '[1,-1]'  1.0  0

It means I would like NAO continuously with certain frequency can moves its head.

I will appreciate if you help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69604/loop-over----$-rostopic-pub-.....---on-nao/) by [Mohsen 2013](https://answers.ros.org/users/5116/mohsen-2013/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should probably write a ROS node to do this, rather than try to script the command-line tools. You may want to start with the [ROS python tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3